# Method should return different values

Tags: java, selenium

I have a method which return and stores the value of the first selected option in a drop down. The value is passed to a pojo class method setApp1. Again, the same method is invoked which stores the value of the selected option and passes it to  pojo class method setApp2.

```
 public String dropDownSelection(String appId){
        Select dropDownList = new Select(selectDropdown);
        dropDownList.selectByValue(appId);
        WebElement option = dropDownList.getFirstSelectedOption();
        String appName = option.getText();
        HeaderPojo hp = new HeaderPojo();
        hp.setApp1(appName);
        //What can i do for setApp2??
        return appName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be possible if you were to create the `HeaderPojo` not in this method but rather pass it as argument.

Then something like that should work:

```
 public String dropDownSelection(String appId, HeaderPojo hp){
        Select dropDownList = new Select(selectDropdown);
        dropDownList.selectByValue(appId);
        WebElement option = dropDownList.getFirstSelectedOption();
        String appName = option.getText();
        if(hp.getApp1() == null)
        {hp.setApp1(appName);}
        else
        {hp.setApp2(appName);}
        return appName;
    }
```

You aren't doing anything with the `HeaderPojo` anyway since it's a locally scoped variable. So why did you even bother to set that value?

Comment: Value of App1 and App2 is later required to invoke a different method.

Comment: Yeah, but you cannot access it in your code since the variable won't be accessable anywhere out of that function.

Comment: I've used static to used it for the method.